# HelloWorld web.py doesn't work

Tags: python, web-server, pip

I've seen web.py recommended in some places as a simple python web framework that I could use in my raspberry, so I went ahead and installed it via PIP (`sudo pip install web.py`).

But when I try to run its hello-world web app (like it's said in the [tutorial](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial)), it gives this error:

```
$ python code.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import web
  File "/home/myuser/mywebapp/web.py", line 6, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'application'
```

What's wrong here? Should I install it from the tarball instead?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code.

Comment: the code is exactly like the one in the tutorial, that's why I added a link to it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to refer the answer below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412442/web-py-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-application

> If so when you do import web you are importing your package not the
>   actual web.py. Rename it, or reorder your pythonpath.